# Still getting the exception "application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread" after using Dispatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, uwp, winrt-async

```
public ObservableCollection<College> Colleges { get; set; }
```

My collection holding College data.

```
    public static Task<College> getCollege(string uniqueid)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>

            Colleges.Where(coll => coll.UniqueID.Equals(uniqueid)).First()
        );
    }
```

Implementation for retrieving individual colleges.

GUI

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var college = await DataSource.getCollege((string)e.Parameter);
        coll_grid.DataContext = college;
    }
```

This was my original implementation and it worked fine, but then I read [Task.Run Etiquette](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) by Stephen Cleary and from the gist of it you shouldn't use Task.Run in the implementation.

So I changed my codes this

```
    public static College getCollege(string uniqueid)
    {
        var match = CollegeData.Colleges.Where(coll => coll.UniqueID.Equals(uniqueid));
        return match.First();
    }
```

GUI

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var college = await Task.Run(() => DataSource.getCollege((string)e.Parameter));
        coll_grid.DataContext = college;
    }
```

I got the "application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread" exception

Then I added CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync to the GUI code to fix this.

GUI

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            var college = await Task.Run(() => DataSource.getCollege((string)e.Parameter);
            coll_grid.DataContext = college;
        });
    }
```

But I am still getting the same exception error. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, there is absolutely no reason for you to use `Task.Run` when doing simple things as finding an element in a list/collection. Just use

```
 coll_grid.DataContext = Colleges.First(coll => coll.UniqueID.Equals(uniqueid))
```

But the reason the `Dispatcher` did not help you is that you need to do just the `DataContext` assignment on it.

```
var college = await Task.Run(() => DataSource.getCollege((string)e.Parameter);
await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
    coll_grid.DataContext = college;
 });
```

Because the call to `await Task.Run(() =>` switches the thread.

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting the same error on this line of code. var college = await Task.Run(() => DataSource.getCollege((string)e.Parameter);